# Direct usage of I/O buffer

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, io

Is it safe to use I/O buffer directly?
For example, I have the following C++ code:

```cpp
    if (setvbuf(inFile, data, _IOFBF, std::size(data)))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("can't set buffering mode");
    }

    fgetc(fileDesc);
    // After getc the bytes from file are presented in data array
    fwrite(data, std::size(data), 1, outFile);
```

It works perfectly well on my Ubuntu. But I'm not sure if accessing data array is allowed.

For example, cppreference says that:

> The contents of the array after a successful call to `setvbuf` are indeterminate and any attempt to use it is undefined behavior.

But the man page of `setvbuf` does not mention anything about usage of I/O buffer.

Does this question have a different answer for the C language? consider this similar code:

```c
    char data[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (setvbuf(inFile, data, _IOFBF, sizeof data))
    {
        perror("can't set buffering mode");
        return -1;
    }

    fgetc(fileDesc);
    // After getc the bytes from file are presented in data array
    fwrite(data, sizeof data, 1, outFile);
```

Comment: The code is C++, don't spam C in tags.

Comment: @273K setvbuf is a C library function and the question is mostly about this function.

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard is less adamant about undefined behavior:

> **7.23.5.6 The `setvbuf` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int setvbuf(FILE * restrict stream, char * restrict buf, int mode, size_t size);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If `buf` is not a null pointer, the array it points to may be used instead of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function and the argument `size` specifies the size of the array; otherwise, `size` may determine the size of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function. The members of the array at any time have unspecified values.

So using the buffer in the way you show in the question does not seem to pose a problem, The Standard just says the buffer contents is unspecified at any time, so writing the buffer twice in a row might even produce different output.  The buffer might not contain the file data: the `setvbuf` implementation could ignore this argument and/or the `size` argument. The contents might also be translated from the actual file data on disk, especially on legacy systems.

Comment: Care should be exercised here.  You appear to have quoted the not-yet-released C23 version of the function spec.  C17, on the other hand, says that the members of the array have *indeterminate* values at any given time. That is semantically different from "unspecified", and would indeed support UB arising from accessing the array elements.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for noticing. I've checked the working draft of C23 and even there the usage of IO array directly is mentioned as undefined behavior (page 591). Thanks!

Comment: @WelcomeToMyTutorial: can you quote the chapter instead of the page number?